# How does docpad pass template data, blocks, and helpers to rendering plugins?

Tags: handlebars.js, docpad

I am trying to build a skeleton to use with marked, less, and handlebars. The handlebars plugin readme is not exactly clear on what the snippet of docpad config code is actually doing (and I cannot seem to get it working I can render the content of my documents out fine but the title attributes etc do not show up). I also noticed an issue suggesting that support could be included into the plugin itself. I am presuming that this is an issue with renders that don't support inline coffeescript the same way eco does.

Does anyone have a better explanation or solution? Alternately, what do I need to understand about docpad's blocks and helpers to contribute a better solution in code or as part of a skeleton?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: Current Docpad Handlebar plugin only support templates within the configuration file. See [this mail thread and the answer @balupton](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docpad/2LPvgtYTrc8). I assume that the only way to have templating, without writing a plugin ourselves, in DocPad is to use ECO.